# Why Unity misses some of my mouse click?

Tags: unity, input, mouse

So i have a simple shooter game, and i need to shoot with mouse click. I use `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)`, but it seems that if I click too fast only a few actually work.

[image]
From the gif above, I've clicked a few times for my gun to fire. I set a duration of 0.1 seconds between shots but it seems it takes longer than that, sometimes it shoots fast and sometimes it doesn't.
I use two script that handle shooting behaviour, one in for weapon:

```
public float offset;
    public GameObject projectile;
    public Transform shotPoint;
    public GameObject player;
    float turnOffset;
    private float timeBtwShots;
    public float startTimeBtwShots;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        
        Vector3 difference=Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition)-transform.position;
        float rotZ=Mathf.Atan2(difference.y,difference.x)*Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        
        if(player.transform.localScale.x==1)turnOffset=0;
        else turnOffset=180;

        transform.rotation=Quaternion.Euler(0f,0f,rotZ+offset+turnOffset);
        if(timeBtwShots<=0){
        
            if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
            Debug.Log("click");
            Instantiate(projectile,shotPoint.position,transform.rotation);

            float transX= (float)(player.transform.localScale.x*0.3);
            projectile.transform.localScale= new Vector3(transX,projectile.transform.localScale.y,projectile.transform.localScale.z);

            BulletBehaviour bulletBehaviour=projectile.GetComponent<BulletBehaviour>();
            if(player.transform.localScale.x==1){
                bulletBehaviour.flip=false;
            }
            else{
                bulletBehaviour.flip=true;
            }
            timeBtwShots=startTimeBtwShots;
        }
        }else{
            timeBtwShots-=Time.deltaTime;
        }
        
    }
```

I set my weapon's localscale based on where my player is currently facing.I also have bullet script that i set to my bullet so it can move:

```
    public float speed;
    public bool flip;
    public float lifeTime;

    private void Start() {
        
        Invoke("DestroyProjectile",lifeTime);
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if(!flip){
            transform.Translate(Vector2.right*speed*Time.deltaTime);
            
            }
        else {
            transform.Translate(Vector2.left*speed*Time.deltaTime);
            }
    }
    void DestroyProjectile(){
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
```

I also set my bullet dirrection based on where my player currently facing.
Is it because i check my mouse click in update function, and not in FixedUpdate? Why is this happening?

Comment: I have never observed this in half a decade of working in Unity. Can you edit your question to show us a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example? Once we can reproduce the problem you're experiencing, we can test potential fixes to be sure they'll work for you.

Comment: maybe i can try to record it

Comment: To clarify: we do not need evidence that the problem occurs. We need the means to recreate the problem ourselves. So please share code, not video.

Comment: ok i have added the code too

Comment: I thought you said you were checking the mouse in Update? This code shows the mouse being checked in FixedUpdate, which is not guaranteed to catch every click, as explained in the docs.

Comment: oo I see, apparently I was confused with my question, what I meant was "Is it because I checked my mouse click in FixedUpdate function, and not in Update?"but i seem to my words get swapped while writing

Comment: So yes it turns out, the problem was because I was using FixedUpdate

Comment: Be sure to read the docs for the methods you're using. [The documentation for GetButtonDown tells you this explicitly](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetButtonDown.html): "You need to call this function from the Update function, since the state gets reset each frame."